# Want the width to be padding + text itself only

Tags: html, css

The width of `.start` should be = text size + padding so I used display inline block, however I get a result something like this.

**DEMO OF THE PROBLEM** 
**http://jsfiddle.net/d4Ajj/8/**

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:**

[image]

```
.bigcontainer
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;
}


.racingbox
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
}


.start
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the element's `display` property to `inline-block`, then yes:

```
.start {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: blue;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d4Ajj/2/).

---

Updated in response to edited question

Given the newly-added HTML, and visual reference, I'd suggest adding the following:

```
.racingbox,
.start {
    /* forces the elements to a new line */
    clear: both;
    /* floats the elements, removing them from the 'normal'
       document-flow, allowing the previous rule to apply */
    float: left;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d4Ajj/10/).

Comment: You're very welcome; do consider accepting the answer if you feel it's answered your question to your satisfaction; you're not obliged to accept an answer (and by all means give it some time to wait for, potentially, better answers).

Comment: I apologize, I tried your suggestion in the code but I got an error. Can you please check the question again? I made an edit and put the fiddle to the question.

Comment: Explain what the 'error' is. Telling us what you've *got* isn't of any use, if we don't know why it's wrong.

Comment: thank you so much sir. Exactly what I wanted. I picked this as chosen answer.